# How to target text field inside iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to target a text field inside an iFrame and give it a value from prent page. I have tried this one but its not working:

```
// b_frame is the ID of the iFrame
$('#b_frame').load(function() {<br />
    $(this.contentDocument).find('body#txtUserID').val('dddddd')<br />
});
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Does the loaded content belong to the same domain as the parent page? If not, it is not possible.

Comment: @Felix Kling, is not in the same domain. What can I do? It's really important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Felix mentioned, it's only possible when the iFrame is the same domain as the main page.

But, you can do so under normal circumstances using [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/). There is a demo towards the bottom of the documentation page, just follow the link.

Comment: @jay: Given your comment to Felix, it's not possible to do what you're asking. Maybe use greasemonkey and have it trigger when that site is visited?

Comment: I just found the way to do it. Since its almost not possible to do it in different url, I just made one new page with a form into my own website and linked my iFrame to it and forced the page with javascript to submit the new form after loading. Because the form is linked to the foreign website, it will relocate iFrame to the new website. Basically I transfer the form content from parent to the new page in iFrame and submit the new page, after submission it will redirect to the page I wanted.